# Fetch the id value and sort them ascending

Tags: jmeter

The response of my get request fetching me following as a JSON format, and I want to fetch all the `id` value and sort them in ascending order in a array and fetch from the beginning and put them in a for each controller, How I can I do it in groovy script?

```
[
    {
        "id": 1410,
        "name": "ESPav2",
        "orgId": "TestServer1",
        "createdDate": "2021-09-23T08:47:39.5553398",
        "isActive": true
    },
    {
        "id": 1406,
        "name": "ESPav1",
        "orgId": "TestServer1",
        "createdDate": "2021-09-23T12:15:32.982959",
        "isActive": true
    },
    {
        "id": 1409,
        "name": "sub1",
        "orgId": "TestServer1",
        "createdDate": "2021-09-23T17:45:58.9410605",
        "isActive": true
    },
    {
        "id": 1408,
        "name": "bl",
        "orgId": "TestServer1",
        "createdDate": "2021-09-24T04:18:26.6323815",
        "isActive": true
    },
    {
        "id": 1407,
        "name": "Test",
        "orgId": "TestServer1",
        "createdDate": "2021-09-24T04:19:07.3712661",
        "isActive": true
    },
    {
        "id": 1405,
        "name": "ESPav2",
        "orgId": "TestServer1",
        "createdDate": "2021-09-24T05:02:58.8471913",
        "isActive": true
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSON JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON and configure it as follows:

   [image]

   textual representation of the JMESPath query just in case:

   ```
   [*].id | sort(@)
   ```
2. Configure the ForEach Controller like this:

   [image]
3. Refer the ID as `${id}` inside the ForEach Controller where required

Demo:
[image]

More information:

- [JMESPath Tutorial](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)
- [JMESPath Functions](https://jmespath.org/proposals/functions.html)
- [The JMeter JSON JMESPath Extractor and Assertion: A Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-jmeter-json-jmespath-extractor-andassertion-a-guide)